# devtools Timeline (now Performance) shows GPU cycling

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am translating a canvas element horizontally across the page, like this:

```
var tx = 0;
function animate() {
  tx -= 1;
  canvas.style.transform = 'translateX(' + tx + 'px)';
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

The issue is I see slight stuttering (jank). Looking at the Performance tab in Canary (or Timeline in Chrome), I see that GPU work goes through a cycle where it starts by taking up the entire frame and slowly diminishes, then jumps to taking up the entire frame again. This cycling pattern seems to correspond to the stuttering.

Anyone have a clue what is causing this, or what I should look for to analyze?

This shows the GPU work cycling:
[image: This shows the GPU work cycling]

This is a close up at the point where a new cycle begins:
[image: This is a close up at the point where a new cycle begins]

Comment: Interesting situation. Can you reproduce in a snippet? I tried using the code sample you provided but can't quite repro the GPU cycling behavior... https://codepen.io/kaycebasques/pen/RVpyMx

Comment: Might be [a bug](https://crbug.com). Also try `will-change: transform`.

Comment: `will-change: transform` had no effect

Comment: @KayceBasques Your codepen shows the same behavior on my beefy Windows PC. However, on my 2012 Mac Air, I don't see the cycling AND there is no visible stuttering in the animation. I think it may not be a bug but rather something low level in the Windows architecture.